# Bootstrap Issue

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I have a `bootstrap` DataTable with a link button inside the grid. The issue is when I click on the show filter results and change the filter value to 20, then records are getting displayed according to the filter search.

But when I click the linkbutton the grid is getting posted back and the filter result and grid are getting refreshed and filter search resets to the original value of 10.

I have attached the screen shot and script

script:

```
 $("#cphKlassAktLMS_gvBusinessGroupDetails").dataTable({

    "aoColumnDefs": [
            { "bSortable": false, "aTargets": [-1, -2] }
        ],

    'bDestroy': true,

    'fnDrawCallback': function () {
        $('td').addClass('WrapText')
        $('.odd').addClass('hover')
        $('.even').addClass('hover')
    },

    "bAutoWidth": false,
    "oLanguage": {
       // "sSearch": "Further filter search results:",
        "sInfo": "Got a total of _TOTAL_ results to show (_START_ to _END_)",
        "sLengthMenu": 'Show <select>' +
'<option value="5">5</option>' +
'<option value="10">10</option>' +
'<option value="15">15</option>' +
'<option value="20">20</option>' +
'<option value="25">25</option>' +
'</select> results'
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Store your filter values in WebStorage and repopulate them using jQuery

```
localStorage.setItem("filtervalue", $('FilterSelector').val());

$('FilterSelector').val(localStorage.getItem("filtervalue"));
```